# New email marked as read when arriving to empty Inbox

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, inbox, incoming-mail

I like to keep my Outlook 2010 Inbox empty. But when a new email arrives, it is automatically selected and viewed in the preview pane, and therefore immediately marked as read. This then removes the "new email" icon from my systray, and therefore I am never notified about the new email.

Short of always keeping an old email in my Inbox, disabling the preview pane, or turning off the "automatically mark viewed email as read", I can't think of any good way to get that systray notification to work.

(I guess lots of GTD folks should have the same issue with their Outlooks.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: yes, you can do .  You can do either using rule or writing plugin or extension. plugin will capture new email event, and then capture emailitem and marked it as read. if you need script let me know.

Comment: That sounds doable - since Outlook is causing my issues, it should be possible to write some incoming email rule that "fixes" its behavior. Thanks for the suggestion!